# Find and replace a variable in multiple HTML files

Tags: regex, perl, replace, grep, find

I want to find and replace a variable in multiple html files using a Perl script.

Specifically, I want to find the "Genus_species" variable in multiple html files and replace it with a new value, a replacement Javascript key/value array. Sounds simple enough, yet I can't figure out how. Please advise. Thanks.

Here's my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::PP;

use English;   ## use names rather than symbols for special variables

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';

opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $OS_ERROR";
my %genus_species;  ## store matching entries in a hash

for my $file (readdir $dfh)
{
    next unless $file =~ /.png$/;  ## entry must have .png extension
    my $genus = $file =~ s/\d*\.png$//r;
    push(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file);   ## push to array,the @{} is to cast the single entry to a reference to an list

}

@{$genus_species{$_}} = sort @{$genus_species{$_}}
   for keys(%genus_species);


my $str = (JSON::PP->new->utf8->canonical->encode(\%genus_species)); ## Assign variable to Javascript key/value array
```

Notice that my Perl script ends with a variable ($str) defining the replacement value for the "Genus_species" variable in my html files. It ends here because I don't know where to go from here, other than knowing that ultimately I want **Genus_species=$str**.

That said, here's one of the html files on which my Perl script will be executing the find and replace function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!--Plant slideshow-->

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--Updating the variable "Genus_species" updates the slideshow-->

var Genus_species={"Acalypha_deamii":["Acalypha_deamii1.png","Acalypha_deamii2.png","Acalypha_deamii3.png"],"Acalypha_ostryifolia":["Acalypha_ostryifolia1.png","Acalypha_ostryifolia2.png"]

var curimg=0
var plant=Genus_species.Polygonum_pensylvanicum <!--Entering the specific "Genus_species" after the "." loads ALL photos of the specified plant into the slideshow-->

function swapImage()
{
   document.getElementById("slide").setAttribute("src", "/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants/"+plant[curimg])
   curimg=(curimg<plant.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0; timer = setTimeout("swapImage()",4000);
}

function stopShow()
{
  clearTimeout(timer);
}

function runShow()
{
  swapImage();  
}
</script>

<body onLoad="runShow()">

<IMG STYLE="position:relative; TOP:35px; LEFT:100px" img id="slide" onMouseover="stopShow()" onMouseout="runShow()" src="" />

</body>
</html>
```

Again, please advise how, using a Perl script, to find the "Genus_species" variable in multiple html files and replace its value with that of the "$str" variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can replace the JSON string in the HTML file using a regex substitution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# assume you have generated the JSON encoding string in variable $replace
my $replace = '{Acalypha_deamii":["Acalypha_deamii1.png","Acalypha_deamii2.png","Acalypha_deamii3.png"],"Acalypha_ostryifolia":["Acalypha_ostryifolia1.png","Acalypha_ostryifolia2.png"]}';

my $fn = 'result.html';
my $str;
{
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    # read the whole file into a string
    $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close $fh;
}
$str =~ s/var Genus_species=\K(.*?)$/$replace/m;
# save the file (overwrites the original)
open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
print $fh $str;
close $fh;
```

Comment: Hakon... Basically, I want to replace everything to the right of the equals sign in the Javascript expression "var Genus_species=". Should the "my $replace=" expression use a regex to define everything that comes after the equals sign? Also, where should the path to the html directory, "/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants/", be specified in your code?

Comment: *"Should the `my $replace=` expression use a regex to define everything that comes after the equals sign?"* I assumed you already had created the `$replace` variable like in the code you posted.

Comment: *"Also, where should the path to the html directory `/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants/` be specified in your code ?"* Do you have the HTML file in the same directory as the `.png` files?

Comment: Okay... I set "my replace=(JSON::PP->new->utf8->canonical->encode(\%genus_species));"... I think that'll work? And, yes, the png files and HTML files are in the same directory.

Comment: *" yes, the png files and HTML files are in the same directory"* Then just change `$fn` to `/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants/result.html` or use the `$dir` variable you already defined in your code: `$fn = $dir . '/result.html';`

Comment: Hakon... Thanks for your help! I think I can make your code work, but I need to resolve several directory/subdirectory issues before doing so. Again, thanks for your help, Hakon. Signing off for now.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to generate html files than try *to edit* them? As a side benefit you will not have to create and maintain files for new species -- script will generate them for you.

**Suggestion:** move common Javascript code into external `slideshow.js` file and only *inject* unique to particular *organism* part of the script into generated html file. It will make files smaller and easier to read, benefits: page loads faster and less parsing for web browser.

**Note:** perhaps OP require to spend a little bit of time to study [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) for webpage styling

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %species;
my $template = do { local $/; <DATA> };

# Do what is required to generate %species hash

for my $organism ( sort keys %species ) {
    my $page = $template;
    my $data = $species{$organism};
    
    $page =~ s/<PLACEHOLDER>/$data/gs;
    
    species_html($organism,$page);
}

sub species_html {
    my $ogranism = shift;
    my $page     = shift;

    my $filename = $organism . '.html';
    
    open my $fh, '>', $filename
        or die "Couldn't to open $filename";
        
    say $fh $page;
        
    close $fh;
}

__DATA__
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!--Plant slideshow-->

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--Updating the variable "Genus_species" updates the slideshow-->

var Genus_species=<PLACEHOLDER>

var curimg=0
var plant=Genus_species.Polygonum_pensylvanicum 
<!--
    Entering the specific "Genus_species" after the "." loads ALL photos
    of the specified plant into the slideshow
-->

function swapImage()
{
   var basedir = "/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants/"
   document.getElementById("slide").setAttribute("src", basedir + plant[curimg])
   curimg=(curimg<plant.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0; timer = setTimeout("swapImage()",4000);
}

function stopShow()
{
  clearTimeout(timer);
}

function runShow()
{
  swapImage();  
}
</script>

<body onLoad="runShow()">

<IMG STYLE="position:relative; TOP:35px; LEFT:100px" img id="slide" onMouseover="stopShow()" onMouseout="runShow()" src="" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Polar Bear, for your coding insights. I agree, I do need to gain a better understanding of coding practices.